# How to count max, min and avg values of a list of input from a user

Tags: c++, max, average, min

guys! I have a midterm next week for c++ and I was given a few exercises to work on. For this one, I'm stumped on how to get the minimum and average values from a list of integers the user inputs. Any help would be well appreciated! :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int num = 0;
    cout << "Enter a list of integers terminated by a negative number: " << endl;


    while(cin >> num)
    {
        if(num >= 0)
        {
            if (num > max)
            {
                max = num;
            }
            if (num < max)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a string stream to break up the user input 2) Use a loop to add these values into an array 3) Loop over the array to pick the min and max and calculate the average. These steps can be condensed, but that is the basic jist.

Comment: 4). Don't initialize your min and max to 0's. What if all your numbers are negative? What if all your numbers are positive?

Comment: For the average value you probably need to keep track of the sum of all values entered so far as well as the number of values entered (so that you can eventually compute the average value).

Comment: Do not forget calculate the average using doubles instead of ints.

Comment: @oopscene You don't really need to do that depending on accuracy requirements. At most you will be off by 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int num = -1;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while ( std::cin >> num && num >= 0) {
            count++;
            if (num > max) {
                max = num;
            }
            if (num < min) {
                min = num;
            }
            sum += num;
    }
    if ( count) {
        std::cout << "min: " << min << std::endl;
        std::cout << "max: " << max << std::endl;
        std::cout << "average: " << (double)sum / count << std::endl;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Using `boost::accumulator`

`boost::accumulator` provides facilities you can easily use for statistics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/min.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/max.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main() {
    // Define an accumulator set for calculating the mean, max, and min
    accumulator_set<double, features<tag::min, tag::max, tag::mean> > acc;

    int num = -1;
    bool empty = true;

    while ( std::cin >> num && num >= 0) {
        empty = false;
        acc( num);
    }

    if ( ! empty) {
        // Display the results ...
        std::cout << "Mean: " << mean( acc) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Min: " << min( acc) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Max: " << max( acc) << std::endl;  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `min=0` is the appropriate initialization?

Comment: yes, it will be changed if there is any valid input

Comment: What about `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`? Would those not be better choices for a *C++* program?

Comment: You can use them, yes, but this is not required.

Comment: @Emmet You can also use boost::accumulator for average.

Comment: @user3403337 you can accept the answer. Do you need further explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in *C++*. It is essentially complete except that it does not exit when a negative number is entered (it will exit on any non-numeric input instead).

The advantage of this solution is that, with very little additional work, it should (unless I've made another error) work for any numeric type (the concept of *average* is not defined for non-numeric types, so that's OK) just by changing the type in the templatized function call in `main()`. If you want something simpler, an earlier “integer only” version is in the edit history of this answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void listStats() {
    T min   = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    T max   = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    T sum   = static_cast<T>(0);
    T value;
    int count = 0; 

    while( std::cin >> value ) {
        max = std::max(max, value);
        min = std::min(min, value);
        sum += value;
        count++;
    }

    if( count > 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Minimum: " << min << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Maximum: " << max << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Average: " << sum/double(count) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No input" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    listStats<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read *my* description, Vlad?

Comment: @Emmet I read. However there is another requirement in the assignment.

Comment: Why don't you provide us with your answer, Vlad? It'd probably be quicker for us all to see how you'd do it rather than play guessing games.

Comment: @Emmet One possible way to hit those exact requirements is to add `&& value >= 0` to the `while` condition; although at this point I hope the OP has enough info to determine that! :)

Comment: Jason-C: I think I'll let the OP do that little task himself. I think it's adequately covered by the parenthetical note in my description. If Vlad has any further problems, I doubt he'll be shy about letting us know.

Comment: @Emmet I think this is not correct because for every type the average has to be double, in case of listStats<int>() you will have integer division,  correct?

Comment: @lizusek: I did think of that, but I think it's arguable. I'm still undecided about it.

Comment: Well one of the properties of mean is that sum of all elements minus n*average has to be 0. This will not hold for such implementation.

Comment: @lizusek: well, that's merely a rearrangement of the definition of arithmetic mean. We're asked for “average” of a list of integers, which is not as clearly defined. A fair integer average or a quotient might be expected. In any case, the change is rather trivial if you don't like your answers being rounded toward 0.

Comment: yes, we are talking about arithmetic mean, I am sure, ask OP in case of doubts

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    bool cont = true;
    int total = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    int average;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int num;

    while(cont)
    {
        cin >> num;
        if(num < 0)
        {
            cont = false;
            break;
        }
        amount++;
        if(amount == 1)
        {
            min = num;
            max = num;
        }
        if(num < min) min = num;
        if(num > max) max = num;
        total += num;
    }

    int average = total/amount;
    printf("Min: %i \nMax: %i \nAverage: %i \n", min, max, average);
}
```

I haven't actually tested this but it should work properly.
Also, you may want to make the average value a float, because making it an int will probably not be precise. If the average is not a whole number, it will be rounded down to an integer. I just made it an integer because all of your values were integers, but really it should be a double or a float.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't really need `cont` there; just a `break` out of a `while (true)` will get you the same thing. :)

Answer (score -2):

At first I would like to point out that you should not use approaches with numeric_limits as it was showed in other posts. it is a very bad approach. To find the maximum or minimum of a sequence of objects all you need is that the type has defined `operator <` You should always try to use general approaches that cover more types. Using some specific characteristics of some types makes your code less flexible and generic. it is simply a bad style of programming. For example let assume that you defined class Point. All you need is to define `operator <` for this class that to find the maximum or the minimum of a sequence of objects of type Point. You need not to specialize standard class `std::numeric_limits` for your class Point as others suggest to do. :) Moreover if for example objects have type `std::string` then there is no specialization of std::numeric-limits for this class. So if you will be ask to find the maximum and minimum among entered strings then you will have to rewrite your code.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int max;
    int min;
    int num;
    int count;
    int sum;
    bool empty;

    cout << "Enter a list of integers terminated by a negative number: " << endl;

    sum = 0; count = 0; empty = true;

    while ( cin >> num && num >= 0 )
    {
        if ( empty )
        {
            max = num;
            min = num;
            empty = false;
        }
        else if ( max < num )
        {
            max = num;
        }
        else if ( num < min )
        {
            min = num;
        }

        ++count;
        sum += num;         
    }

    if ( !empty )
    {
        cout << "minimum value = " << min << endl;      
        cout << "maximum value = " << max << endl;      
        cout << "average value = " << sum / count << endl;      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is simple to write a generic function that can be used even with objecs of type `std::string`
For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>


enum { MAX, MIN, SUM, CNT };

template <typename T>
bool GetInfo( std::tuple<T, T, T, size_t> &t )
{
    bool empty;
    T min;
    T max;
    T sum;
    T num;
    size_t cnt;

    sum = T(); cnt = 0; empty = true;

    while ( std::cin >> num && !( num < T() ) )
    {
        if ( empty )
        {
            max = num;
            min = num;
            empty = false;
        }
        else if ( max < num )
        {
            max = num;
        }
        else if ( num < min )
        {
            min = num;
        }

        sum = sum + num;
        ++cnt;
    }

    if ( !empty )
    {
        std::get<MAX>( t ) = max;
        std::get<MIN>( t ) = min;
        std::get<SUM>( t ) = sum;
        std::get<CNT>( t ) = cnt;
    }

    return !empty;
}


int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string, size_t> t;

    std::cout << "Enter strings (Ctrl+Z - exit): ";

    bool non_empty = GetInfo( t );

    if ( non_empty )
    {
        std::cout << "maximum string is " << std::get<MAX>( t ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "minimum string is " << std::get<MIN>( t ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "total string   is " << std::get<SUM>( t ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "average lemgth is " << std::get<SUM>( t ).size() / std::get<CNT>( t )
                                          << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If to enter for example

abc def ghi
and after pressed key ENTER to press Ctrl + Z

then output will be

```
Enter strings (Ctrl+Z - exit): abc def ghi
^Z
maximum string is ghi
minimum string is abc
total string   is abcdefghi
average lemgth is 3
```

In fact this function combines two standard algorithms: `std::minmax_element` and `std::accumulate` together with function `std::distance` that are used for an input iterator. Standard algorithm `std::minmax_element` (or corresponding algorithms `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`) are never written using `std::numeric_traits.` They use general approach that suitable for all types that have defined `operator <`
You could write a template function with input iterator as template parameter.

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
GetInfo ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
          std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, 
                     typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, 
                     typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type> &t, 
          UnaryPredicate unary_predicate );
```

The template function I showed above also can be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>


enum { MAX, MIN, SUM };

template <typename T, typename UnaryPredicate>
size_t GetInfo( std::tuple<T, T, T> &t, UnaryPredicate unary_predicate )
{
    T min;
    T max;
    T sum;
    T num;
    size_t cnt;

    sum = T(); cnt = 0;

    while ( std::cin >> num && !unary_predicate( num ) )
    {
        if ( cnt == 0 )
        {
            max = num;
            min = num;
        }
        else if ( max < num )
        {
            max = num;
        }
        else if ( num < min )
        {
            min = num;
        }

        sum = sum + num;
        ++cnt;
    }

    if ( cnt != 0 )
    {
        std::get<MAX>( t ) = max;
        std::get<MIN>( t ) = min;
        std::get<SUM>( t ) = sum;
    }

    return cnt;
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, int, int> t;

    std::cout << "Enter non-negaruve integers (-1 - exit): ";

    size_t cnt = GetInfo( t, std::bind2nd( std::equal_to<int>(), -1 ) );

    if ( cnt )
    {
        std::cout << "maximum value is " << std::get<MAX>( t ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "minimum value is " << std::get<MIN>( t ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "total value   is " << std::get<SUM>( t ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "average value is " << std::get<SUM>( t ) / cnt
                                          << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not seem meaningful to calculate `mean` over a different domain than `min` and `max`; where the latter are using lexicographic order, the former uses the length. The only way to make these match is to make `min` and `max` operate on lengths as well -- the current definition of "average string = average string length" seems to be a stretch to try and arbitrarily define this for non-numeric types. Also I'd recommend against the use of a `tuple`, which contains no semantic information (can be mixed with a `tuple` that means something else entirely).

Comment: Additionally, the use of an `enum` to hack indexes in a tuple places semantic meaning to the *value* of the enums (e.g. `enum {MIN=3,MAX=4,SUM=5}` does not work), but enums are intended to convey semantics in *name*. It would be clearer, safer, and semantically more relevant to define a `struct { T min, max, mean; }`. This solution sidesteps all good-practice means of checking semantics at compile time; it's not really the best use of C++'s features.